# Assertion `str' failed

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am new bee for c++ . I got follow error when I override operator+ .

> ConsoleApplication1.out: /root/projects/ConsoleApplication1/sdstring.cpp:43: static sdstring::size_t sdstring::strlen(const char*): Assertion `str' failed.

This is my test code!

```
    sdstring sd1(NULL);
    cout << "sd1：" << sd1 << endl;
    sdstring sd2("sd2");
    cout << "sd2：" << sd2 << endl;
    sdstring sd3;
    cin >> sd3;
    cout << "sd3：" << sd3 << endl;

    sd3 +=sd2 ;
    cout << "sd3：" << sd3 << endl;
    sdstring sd4 =sd3+sd1;
    cout << "sd4：" << sd2 << endl;
    sd1 = sd2 + sd1;
    cout << "sd1：" << sd1 << endl;
    cout << "sd3==sd2:" << (sd3 == sd2)<<endl;
```

Error happened in This line .

`sdstring sd4 =sd3+sd1;`

This is my sdstring.cpp file.

```
#include "sdstring.h"
#include <assert.h>



sdstring::sdstring(const char *str) {
    if (!str) {
        datas = new char[1];
        datas[0] = '\0';
    }
    else {
        datas = new char[strlen(str)+1];
        strcpy(datas, str);
    }
}
sdstring::sdstring(const sdstring& str) {
    datas = new char[strlen(str.datas) + 1];
    strcpy(datas, str.datas);
}
sdstring& sdstring::operator+(const sdstring& str)const {
    sdstring result(NULL);
    size_t total_size = getlen() + str.getlen();
    result.datas = new char[total_size + 1];
    strcpy(result.datas, datas);
    strcat(result.datas, str.datas);
    return result;
}

bool sdstring::operator==(const sdstring& str)const {
    return strcmp(datas, str.datas) == 0;
}
sdstring& sdstring::operator=(const sdstring& str) {
    if (this == &str)
        return *this;
    delete[] datas;
    datas = new char[str.getlen() + 1];
    strcpy(datas, str.datas);
    return *this;
}


sdstring::size_t sdstring::strlen(const char* str) {
    assert(str);
    size_t len = 0;
    while ('\0' !=  *str++)
        len++;
    return len;
}
char* sdstring::strcpy( char* des, const char* src){
    assert(des&& src);
    char* temp = des;
    while ('\0' != (*des++ = *src++));
    return temp;
}
int sdstring::strcmp(const char* fir, const char* sec) {
    assert(fir  && sec);
    while (*fir == *sec)
    {
        if (*fir == '\0') {
            return 0;
        }
        ++fir;
        ++sec;
    }
    return *fir - *sec;
}

char* sdstring::strcat(char* des,const char* src) {
    char* temp = des;
    while ('\0' != *des)
    {
        des++;
    }
    while ('\0' != (*des++ = *src++));
    return temp;
}

sdstring::~sdstring()
{
    if (datas)
    {
        delete[] datas;
        datas = nullptr;
    }
}
char& sdstring::operator[](const unsigned int position)const
{
    return position < getlen() ? datas[position] : datas[position-1];
}
sdstring& sdstring::operator+=(const sdstring& str)
{
    size_t total_size = getlen() + str.getlen();
    if (total_size != getlen()) {
        char* temp = datas;
        datas = new char[total_size + 1];
        strcpy(datas,temp);
        strcat(datas, str.datas);
        delete[] temp;
    }
    return *this;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const sdstring& str)
{
    os << str.datas;
    return os;
}
 istream& operator>>(istream& is, sdstring& str)
{
     char* cache = new char[1024];
     is >> cache;
     delete[]str.datas;
     str.datas = new char[sdstring::strlen(cache)];
     sdstring::strcpy(str.datas, cache);
     delete[]cache;
     return is;
}
```

Who can help me , Thanks for first!

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: Removed C tag.  This is a C++ question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code.  However the `operator +` is wrong in that it is returning a reference to a local variable, which is undefined behavior.

```
sdstring& sdstring::operator+(const sdstring& str)const 
{
    sdstring result(NULL);
    //..
    return result;  // Undefined behavior.
}
```

`operator +` should be returning a brand new object, not a reference to an object.

```
sdstring sdstring::operator+(const sdstring& str)const // <-- Note the return value is sdstring
{
    sdstring result(NULL);
    //..
    return result;  
}
```

The other issues with your code:

1) The `operator=` destroys the memory using `delete[] datas;` before calling `new[]` to allocate memory for the new string.  If `new[]` throws an exception, the `sdstring` object would be corrupted since the data has been destroyed and you can't go back and reset the string with the old data.  Use the [copy / swap idiom to prevent this from happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

2) You should store the length of the string in a member variable instead of calling `strlen` every time you want to know the length of the string.  The `strlen` is slow in that it has to loop to count every single character to determine where the terminating '\0' character is located.  Instead of that, just store the length of the string once and keep using that value.

3) Instead of writing your own `strlen` and `strcmp` functions, use the library functions `strlen` and `strcmp`.  Your versions are not optimized, unlike the library versions.

4) `operator +` can be written in terms of `operator +=`.  `operator +` should be written very simply as:

```
sdstring sdstring::operator + (const sdstring& rhs)
{
   return sdstring(*this) += rhs;
}
```

Comment: You are so kind ,Thanks for your patience for my  silly question .I will fix those issues .